# How to get bitblt to copy child controls without painting the child controls to the screen?

Tags: c#, bitblt

**Here is the short of my question:** in a custom control, is there a way to get a parent paint/bitblt its children controls to a background image, but not have the children controls actually paint on the control?

**Details:**
I am trying to roll my own double buffering (on the compact framework) and am having a lot of problems.  I have a fairly complex user control.  It has a view `Panel` (fixed size) with scroll `Panel` (variable size) in it.  The scroll `Panel` has several card `Panels` in it.  The card panels are stacked vertically contain two `DataGrids` and two `Labels`.

Here is a visual outline of my control

```
View Panel
    |
    +--> Scroll Panel
              |
              +---> Card Panel
              |        |
              |        +--> Label
              |        +--> Label
              |        +--> Data Grid
              |        +--> Data Grid
              |
              +---> Card Panel
              |        |
              |        +--> Label
              |        +--> Label
              |        +--> Data Grid
              |        +--> Data Grid
            (...)
```

OK, so now to the problem.  I override the on paint for the Scroll Panel and do a bitblt to get an image to show as a "custom painting".  I tested the image by saving it off and it is exactly what I want.

The problem is that the datagrids and labels still do their normal painting.  So when I scroll then are leaving artifacts behind.  So, I override the OnPaint to do nothing for the grid and the label.  But when I do that the bitblt does not pickup the grids anymore (but oddly it picks up the labels still).

So, in a custom control, is there a way to get a parent paint/bitblt its children controls to a background image, but not have the children controls actually paint on the control?

NOTE: If you are interested to see my full code you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/840096).

Comment: *Where does `BitBlt` get the image to copy from?* You specify it as an argument to the function.